Can I make JSF faster with componentCache if yes where?
Jsf Implementations are a litle bit slow because of searching components by clientId with recursive iteration, or visitTree methods.
We made first a mojarra patch 2.1.18...
FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy,FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy,FaceletViewHandlingStrategy..
In all three classes we removed
locateComponentByClientId method
and made a Map<String,UIComponent> with SKIP_ITERATION_HINT full visitree.
Our applications are a little bit faster. (Perhaps 30%)
I wonder a little bit, that FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy,FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy locate logic is the same but the third one is very different, why?
When is the FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.locateComponentByClientId function called?
Why isn't cached Component tree by id in Mojarra or other implementation? (Is very dynamic the clientId?)
If you built a Component Cache in Mojaraa where you will implement it?
We saw some years before by a perfromance test, that a lot of thread run in a visitree function. So we built a map, and with client Id cached the components.
private static final Set<VisitHint> SKIP_ITERATION_HINT = EnumSet.of(SKIP_ITERATION);

public Map<String, UIComponent> createCompCache(FacesContext context) {
    final Map<String, UIComponent> compCache = new HashMap<>();
  try {
    context.getAttributes().put(SKIP_ITERATION_HINT, true);
    Set<VisitHint> hints = EnumSet.of(VisitHint.SKIP_ITERATION);
    VisitContext visitContext = VisitContext.createVisitContext(context, null, hints);

    context.getViewRoot().visitTree(visitContext, (visitContext1, component) -> {
      compCache.put(component.getClientId(visitContext.getFacesContext()), component);
      return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
    });
    return compCache;
  } finally {
    context.getAttributes().remove(SKIP_ITERATION_HINT);
  }
}

And we chached this rows
UIComponent child = locateComponentByClientId(context, parent, struct.getClientId());

to this
UIComponent child = compCache.get(struct.getClientId());

We haven't made stressztest today in this new mojarra, but we think it is useful. Last stressztest was run in wildfly26's mojarra.
@BalusC or other JSF expert :) If you have some useful idea about this patch we want to make and push as PR the main branch.
If there is a better place to make this component cache, it could be faster.
Perhaps we can change invokeOnComponent methods too. I think a map is faster than a children iterator.
Thank a lot your opinion.

2.1.18 is really ancient (2013!). A couple of optimizations were done in later versions. What's holding you back to upgrade to the latest 2.3.x? It's supposed to be fully backwards compatible.

I wrote this our first patch was on 2.1.18. Today I read and wrote it org.mojarra 4.0.7 (wildfly 33). So that patch could be actually today too.

Sorry, my english :) I could have savedActions 100(n) savedAction by on call. My component tree could have 500(m) components. visitTree 100 times is ~ O(nm). But if i build a hashmap then O(m+nlog(m)).
